# javascript conditional expression parser

Tags: javascript

I am working in JavaScript. I want to parse  and evaluate conditional expression.
**ex:**

```
    var param1=1;
    var param2=2;
    var param3=3;
    var expression="(param1==param2)||(param3<param1)";
```

I want to write a function which will accept 'expression' as a input and parse the expression as well as evaluate expression and return evaluated result.

Please let me know for any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not have a function expression as input? Where does the "conditional expression" come from? What grammar do you want?

Comment: in my application user enters conditional expression manually and accordingly it should evaluate.

Comment: Are those expressions only used for the user who entered them? If not, you should not use `eval` and co, intead use a parser and evaluate them manually. The grammar should be quite trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the evil one: eval();

```
var param1=1;
var param2=2;
var param3=3;
var expression=eval("(param1==param2)||(param3<param1)");
```

Then your function comes,

```
function myEvaluator(s) {
    return eval(s);
}
```

You must have variables in expression public.

Comment: eval function is not working as expected for conditional expression. var expression=eval(1==2) it returns true instead of false.

Comment: no it does not, but using `eval` for evaluating input you don't control is very risky. If you want to do it properly you have no other choice than getting or writing your own boolean statements evaluator/parser. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question and I am surprised that no libraries came out since to help with this.

Out of necessity, I built a library called [angel-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angel-eval) that does exactly that. It parses a string expression and evaluates with a context object. It uses a parser generator called Nearley under the hood and does not use `eval` or `new Function(…)`.

To use, install: `npm i angel-eval`

```js
const { evaluate } = require("angel-eval");

evaluate("(param1===param2)||(param3<param1)", { param1: 1, param2: 2, param3: 3 });
```

`angel-eval` does not support `==` or `!=` so you need to use `===` and `!==`.

Here is a sandbox:

[image: Edit angel-eval]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few expression parsers out there, but I would like to suggest mine. It's called [swan-js](https://github.com/onlabsorg/swan-js/blob/main/README.md) and it doesn't use eval or new Function.

Installation:

```
npm install @onlabsorg/swan-js
```

Usage (it works both in NodeJS and in the browser):

```js
const swan = require('@onlabsorg/swan-js');
const evaluate = swan.parse("param1 == param2 | param3 < param1");
const context = swan.createContext({param1:1, param2:2, param3:3});
const value = await evaluate(context); // false
```